# Manipulating Json to remove redundant data c#

Tags: c#

I want to return a singular json object with all distinct fields inside that object. The below code generates this json which returns three entries in value where are the same except for the last two fields.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "name": "russ",
      "id": "12345",
      "grade": 5,
      "TestID": "12332",
      "testResult": "Pass"
    },
    {
     "name": "russ",
      "id": "12345",
      "grade": 5,
      "TestID": "15474",
      "testResult": "Pass"
    },
    {
      "name": "russ",
      "id": "12345",
      "gradeLevel": 5,
      "TestID": "75783",
      "testResult": "Fail"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code that performs a web request to get this data

```
var result = Helper.DoRequest(requestUrl, null, httpMethod, "");  
var jObj = JObject.Parse(result.Last().Value.ToString());   
JArray valueList = JArray.Parse(jObj["value"].ToString());
```

I would like to consolidate that into:

```
{
"value": [
    {
      "name": "russ",
      "id": "12345",
      "grade": 5,
      "TestID": "12332",
      "testResult": "Pass"
      "TestID": "15474",
      "testResult": "Pass"
      "TestID": "75783",
      "testResult": "Fail"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code may be a start. It deserializes the json into classes, and groups the results by Name, ID and Grade (I'm assuming the 'gradelevel' key in the third result was a typo) and then outputs that as Json with the test results as an array (your desired output is not valid Json as it contains duplicate key names):

```cs
void Main()
{
    var json = json_from_api;

    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    var groupedResults = results.value.GroupBy(r => new { r.id, r.name, r.grade });

    var finalResults = groupedResults.Select(g => new
    {       
            g.Key.id,
            g.Key.name,
            g.Key.grade,
            test_results = g.ToList().Select(v => new
            {
                v.TestID,
                v.testResult
            }
    )});

    var output = new {
        value = finalResults
    };

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
}

public class Value
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int grade { get; set; }
    public string TestID { get; set; }
    public string testResult { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "name": "russ",
      "grade": 5,
      "test_results": [
        {
          "TestID": "12332",
          "testResult": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "TestID": "15474",
          "testResult": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "TestID": "75783",
          "testResult": "Fail"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed!